# how to find matching records from 3 different files in unix

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

I have 3 different files. 
Test1.txt , Test2.txt & Test3.txt

**Test1.txt** contains

```
JJTP@yahoo.com
BBMU@ssc.com
HK@glb.com
```

**Test2.txt** contains

```
SFTY@gmail.com
JJTP@yahoo.com
```

**Test3.txt** contains

```
JJTP@yahoo.com
HK@glb.com
```

I would like to see only matching records in these 3 files.

so the matching records in above example will be JJTP@yahoo.com
The output should be

```
JJTP@yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you'd do with `awk`:

```
awk '
FILENAME == ARGV[1] { a[$0]++ }
FILENAME == ARGV[2] && ($0 in a) { b[$0]++ }
FILENAME == ARGV[3] && ($0 in b)' file1 file2 file3
```

#### Output:

```
JJTP@yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have duplicate lines in each file then:

```
$ awk '++a[$1]==3' test[1-3]
JJTP@yahoo.com
```

Comment: That may give false positives, if a line is repeated thrice in a single file

Comment: Very clever way to do it, thumbs up.

Comment: If 3 file names are different ( not all are test1/2/3) in that case how will I achieve this ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an `awk` that has a mix of jaypal and sudo_o solution.
It will not give false positive since it test for uniqueness of the lines.

```
awk '!a[$1 FS FILENAME]++ && ++b[$1]==3' test*
JJTP@yahoo.com
```

---

If you have a unknown number of files, this could be an option

```
awk '!a[$1 FS FILENAME]++ && ++b[$1]==ARGC-1' test*
```

The `ARGC` store the number of files read by `awk` + 1

Answer (score 1):

`comm` lists common lines for two files. Just find the common lines in the first two files, then pipe the output to `comm` again and find the common lines with the third file.

```
comm -12 <(sort Test1.txt) <(sort Test2.txt) | comm -12 - <(sort Test3.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the common lines in *two* files, you can use:

```
  sort Test1.txt Test2.txt | uniq -d
```

Or, if you wish to preserve the order found in Test1.txt, you may use:

```
  while read x; do grep -w "$x" Test2.txt; done < Test1.txt
```

For *three* files, repeat this:

```
  sort Test1.txt Test2.txt | uniq -d | sort - Test3.txt | uniq -d
```

Or:

```
  cat                           Test1.txt       |\
  while read x; do grep -w "$x" Test2.txt; done |\
  while read x; do grep -w "$x" Test3.txt; done
```

The `sort` method assumes that the files themselves don't have duplicate lines; if so, you may need create temporary files.

If you wish to use `sed` rather than `grep`, try `sed -n "/^$x$/p"`.